# Maven Site Lifecycle

Tags: maven

So every bit of documentation I've been able to find [about Maven and it's lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) says that site only has 4 phases:

```
pre-site
site
post-site
site-deploy
```

However, in my pom.xml I have an ant script that gets run on the validate phase. According to the "site lifecycle", validate isn't a phase, but my ant script gets run... twice! Not only that, it also compiles my source and runs tests (which takes FOREVER).

What gives, Maven? Your documentation doesn't match your runtime behavior.

Help?

**Edit:**

A plug-in, that explains it. Thanks, I'm using this reporting plugin:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.13</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I found [this documentation on surefire report plug-in](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/) to be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some Maven plugins (like javadoc, for example) declare a 'forked lifecycle'. So, most likely, you have a plugin in your reporting configuration that demands a lifecycle that includes validate. If you are using an up-to-date copy of Maven (3.0.4), the -X option will include, amongst the thousands of lines of useless stuff, readable indications of this forking activity.

Comment: Pretty old question but maybe someone else stumbles over this question. This might help more directly: [Generate Javadoc without duplicate execution of phase generate-sources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin//examples/javadoc-nofork.html)